# How to change a column's datatype from text to datetime in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I'm trying this but it's not working. My original data is formatted like this month/date/year (eg: `2/24/20`)

```sql
UPDATE Packages SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %T'); 
ALTER TABLE Packages MODIFY COLUMN `date` DATETIME;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new datetime column and populate it using `STR_TO_DATE` with the text date:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Packages ADD COLUMN new_date DATETIME;
UPDATE Packages SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d %T');
```

If you'd like, you may also drop the original `date` column, and then rename the new column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Packages DROP COLUMN date;
ALTER TABLE Packages RENAME COLUMN new_date TO date;
```

Answer (score 0):

> My original data is formatted like this month/date/year (eg: 2/24/20)

Use function with the parsing pattern which matches your current format (the function needs in pattern which should be used for parsing, not the pattern which the data must be converted to):

```
STR_TO_DATE(varchar_column, '%m/%e/%y')
```

Look for complete pattern description [there](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).